# X does not have valid feature names

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, knn

I am trying to make a simple fruit classifier with knn classifier but it shows the warning "*X does not have valid feature names, but KNeighborsClassifier was fitted with feature names*". Please tell me how to deal with it ?
Here is the code-

```
# first example: a small fruit with mass 20g, width 4.3 cm, height 5.5 cm
fruit_prediction = knn.predict([[20, 4.3, 5.5]])
lookup_fruit_name[fruit_prediction[0]]
```

Error -

```
C:\Users\mebub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:439: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but KNeighborsClassifier was fitted with feature names
  warnings.warn(
```

I was trying to run a classifier code to determine the name of the fruit with the help of some features.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you showed actually is not an error but a warning. Your code is still running just fine. The warning is telling you that in the dataset on which the KNN was trained, the features were given a name. And it is warning you that the new data that you are feeding it, the names are not specified. So you *could* make mistakes there.

If you want to get rid of the warning, add the following code before you predict.

```
knn.feature_names_in_ = None
```